# Replace Fragment and remove old Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

This is my main XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/fragment_place" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

This is my Main Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_place, new ThirdClass());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

This is ThirdClass

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment1, container, false);
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_place, new FourthClass());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    return v;
}
```

This is the layout of ThirdClass

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"><TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Second Fragment"/></LinearLayout>
```

This is the FourthClass

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_frag, container, false);
    return v;
}
```

And the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"><TextView android:layout_width=" android:layout_height=" android:text="Third Fragment"/></LinearLayout>
```

My question is that those fragments are being saved not replacing each other and it shows me this.[image]

Comment: why are you doing fragment transactions inside onCreateView() of a fragment? Regardless, use replace() instead of add()...

Comment: I'm doing the transactions just to test, the replacing is working, thanks! But are the fragment 'behind' last one still active, it is bad for the application? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `fragmentTransaction.replace()` instead of `fragmentTransaction.add()`

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)):

> Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is
>   essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently
>   added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then
>   add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.